# NodeJS Selenium how to set relative path to webdriver?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Now i have those error:

```
Error: The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
```

I will run script at another computer, so setting environment variable not better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the script into your project directory and use

```js
let options = new Options();
const path = join(__dirname, './yourdriver')
options.setBinary(path)
let builder = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome')
builder = builder.setChromeOptions(options)
let driver = await builder.build();
```

Else

```js
let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let path = require('chromedriver').path;
let service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
```

Dont forget to run `npm i --save chromedriver`

Comment: setBinary is not a function